# Discrete Fourier transform of an exponential decay

Tags: exponential-distribution, fourier-transform, numpy

I have a vector with an exponential decay signal, using Numpy:

```
t=np.arange(128)
a=0.1
decay=np.exp(-a*t)
```

I would like to compute the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of `decay` so I get the same result as applying [`np.fft.rfft(decay, n=128)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html). I tried the formula described [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformExponentialFunction.html) plus some similar ones (without square terms in the denominator) but I never got the same result. The final result I want seems to be a one-sided [Lorentzian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LorentzianFunction.html)? The reason I want to do this is because computing a Lorentzian is faster than computing an exponential and then applying fft.

To summarize, is there an easy way to compute the DFT for a given exponential decay function of known `a`?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that the formula you linked is for the Fourier Transform, and not the Discrete Fourier Transform.

Presumably your range is $[0,127]$, as the DFT requires a finite domain. In which case the [coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) will be

$X_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-kn}e^{-2\pi i kn/N}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-Ck}=\frac{1-e^{-NC}}{1-e^{-C}},$

where $C:=k+2\pi i/N$, and $N=128$.

Comment: Looks good. Except I originally used `exp(-k*t)`, now renamed to `exp(-a*t)`, and the convention in the field is to dessignate coefficients as $X_k$, so it is a bit confusing which $k$ is which